# Loop to read data from a serial to a database

Tags: python, mysql

I want to make a loop to be storing data from serial database. The code I have goes through the first loop but fails to execute in the next loops. Here is the code:

```
import serial 
import MySQLdb
import time
dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","testing") or die ("could not connect to database")
cursor = dbConn.cursor()
device = '/dev/ttyACM0'
max=30
start=time.time()
while True:
    try:
        print "Trying...",device 
        arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600) 
    except: 
        print "Failed to connect on",device    

    try: 
        data = arduino.readline()  
        pieces = data.split("\t")  

        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO productCount (line,count) VALUES (%s,%s)", (pieces[0],pieces[1]))
            dbConn.commit() 
            cursor.close()  
        except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
            print "failed to insert data"
        #finally:
            #cursor.close()
    except:
        print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
    time.sleep(10)
    print "looping..."
    remaining=max+start-time.time()
    print "%s seconds remaining" % int(remaining)
    if remaining<=0:
        cursor.close()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You closed the `cursor` inside while loop. in `try` and `finally`.Put this in break condition of `while loop`

```
cursor.close()
```

Put it outside, or put this inside while loop

```
cursor = dbConn.cursor()
```

Comment: Thanks man. But i have tried the two suggestions but am still getting the same problem. Can you please show me how u are doing it in the full code.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. was writing exams so i had to put the project on hold. above is the updated code